# How to get horizontal bars with ChartJS?

Tags: chart.js

With the official ChartJS documentation, I'm trying to get horizontal bars for each of my data. I tried using x or y, changing options or datasets with no success. I should point out that there is no other JS or SCSS applied on this . How to have horizontal bars? Thanks a lot!

Result :

[image: result]

twig

```
<canvas id="skills{{ i }}"> </canvas>
```

JS

```
    var chartContainer2 = document.getElementById('skills0');
    var ctxSkills = chartContainer2.getContext('2d');

    const data = {
        labels: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
        datasets: [{
            axis: 'y',
            label: 'My First Dataset',
            data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40],
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 205, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(201, 203, 207, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
                'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
                'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
                'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
                'rgb(153, 102, 255)',
                'rgb(201, 203, 207)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    };
    var chartBar = new Chart(chartContainer2, {
        type: 'bar',
        data,
        options: {
            indexAxis: 'y',
            scales: {
                x: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                    stacked: true
                },
                y: [{
                    stacked: true
                }]
            },
        }
    });
```

I would also like the numbers on the left to start from 0 to 100 (I tried to do it with x : min/max but it doesn't work)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `indexAxis: 'y'` is not working for you, it seems you are using V2 of chart.js in this case you need to specify the type as `'horizontalBar'` instead of `'bar'`

Comment: `options: {scales: {xAxes: [{ticks: {min: 0, max: 100}}]}}`